# Past simple and "all night"

Tags: past-tense

can i use just past simple in this case "

> Sorry, I'm late because **I was** in a sauna with Johnny Depp and Angelina
>   Jolie **all last night**

"If I have "all last night is it ok to use just past simple or I better to say:

> Sorry, i'm late because **I was being** in a sauna with Johnny Depp and Angelina Jolie **all last night**"

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence is ungrammatical, because "being" is usually followed by a state or condition, not a location, such as

> I was being happy.

Also "all last night" is a bit stilted; from the context, it wasn't any other night.

Finally I would use the definite article here, though I can't explain why. So the sentence becomes

> Sorry, I'm late because I was in the sauna with Johnny Depp and Angelina Jolie all night.